# Angular 5 Navigation Cancelled with Guard

Tags: angular, routes

I have my routing configured as mentioned below.

```
const PUBLIC_ROUTES: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
{ path: 'session-transfer/:id', component: SessionTransferComponent }
];

const SECURE_ROUTES: Routes = [
{ path: 'clients', component: ClientSelectionComponent },
{ path: 'app/:application', component: SessionTransferComponent },
{ path: 'applications', component: AppSelectionComponent },
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'clients', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'st/:transferId',canActivate: [AuthGuard], canActivateChild: [AuthGuard], children: SECURE_ROUTES },
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full', },
{ path: '', component: PublicComponent, children: PUBLIC_ROUTES },
{ path: '', component: SecureComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], canActivateChild: [AuthGuard], children: SECURE_ROUTES }
];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Following is my sample AuthGuard code

```
_canActivate() {
  return true;
}

canActivate(
next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | 
boolean {

return this._canActivate();
}

canActivateChild(
next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | 
boolean {
     return this._canActivate();
}
```

When I navigate to route `st/:transferId/app/:application` the navigation cancels. In the trace log GuardCheckEnd `ShouldActivate` returning true. Even then the nvigation cancels and redirects to `/login` route.

Can anyone please help. Thanks

Comment: Can you, instead of putting external images, put real formatted code so your question is self-sufficient ?

Comment: You need to put your code between backquote (`), not single quote (')

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason for your error lies here:

```
        const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'st/:transferId',canActivate: [AuthGuard], canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],children: SECURE_ROUTES }, 
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full', }, { path: '', component: PublicComponent, children: PUBLIC_ROUTES }, 
    { path: '', component: SecureComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], canActivateChild: [AuthGuard], children: SECURE_ROUTES } ];
```

Angular uses routes based on the order on which they are arranged. In your case, you have three routes to the same path. Thus angular will use the first route in the Routes array that matches the path, which is login.

My suggestion for this is

1. Let the guards manage the redirect to login. For example,in the AuthGuard service,

   ```
   if(!this._activate){
        this.router.navigate(['/login'])}
   else{
       return this._activate
    }
   ```
2. Give public routes and secure routes unique paths rather than an empty string and finally remove the redirectTo login from the routes.

Comment: Angular takes the route that matches first right. In the order they registered it will pick `st/:transferId/app/:application`. Also it is matching the route `st/:transferId/app/:application`. After the GuardsCheck end event the navigation is getting cancelled and redirected to login